# What css can be used in FullCalendar 5?

Tags: css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to add css to my FullCAlendar 5 Events using 'classNames:'; e.g.,

```
classNames : cssItalic,
```

When I define the cssItalic css as:

```
.cssItalic {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

It works. However, when I change it to:

```
.cssItalic {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The underlining is not done (i.e., bold and italic work).

So, what css can be used with FullCalendar 5?

After further testing I found the the underline is shown in the list view however, not in the month, week and day views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the elements you're trying to underline, you'll notice that they have a style definition already:

```css
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]){
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: auto;
}
```

Your problem is that `.cssItalic` is not as [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as the existing selector that sets `text-decoration`. This is why bold and italics still work, but underline does not for these elements.

Your two options are: make the selector more specific, or use `!important` for the `text-decoration` rule.

Comment: Thank you I added !important and it now underlines; however, the underline is hard to see so I added text-decoration-thickness: 5px !important;. However, this only increases the thickness of the line under the time not under the title. The display is time title (e.g., 10:00 - 11:00 Morcombe,Eric).